# sql - problems with conditional WHERE clause with CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I've looked through some of the questions asked already on this subject but none answered mine.

I have a table where a column can hold numbers and nulls

Depending on the id I'm sending in to my stored procedure, I either have to select where the id's are null or match the id or all of them.

Here's what I have but it doesn't work.

pi_region_id = 51 means I need all the hrcc_id = null

pi_region_id is not 51 or 52 then hrcc_id = pi_region_id

else (meaning it's 52), return them all

```
SELECT i.indicator_id AS ID, 
        i.indicator_name_en AS name_en,
        h.region_code
      FROM indicators i
      JOIN hrcc h ON h.hrcc_id = i.hrcc_id
      WHERE (CASE WHEN pi_region_id = 51 THEN i.hrcc_id IS NULL
                  WHEN pi_region_id != 51 OR pi_region_id != 52 THEN i.hrcc_id := pi_region_id
                  ELSE NULL END)
      ORDER BY i.hrcc_id ASC
```

Oracle give me a "ORA-00905: missing keyword" with the error seeming to be on the i.hrcc_id IS NULL.

I'm still very much novice in pl/sql so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

UPDATE

Example of my tables

INDICATORS

INDICATOR_ID | INDICATOR_NAME_EN | HRCC_ID

1            | Something         | (null)

2            | Another           | 1

3            | Again             | 2

HRCC

HRCC_ID      | REGION_CODE

1            | QC

2            | ON

(sorry... couldn't get it to look better)

What I need is when:

pi_region_id = 51 to return only rows in INDICATORS where HRCC_ID IS NULL

pi_region_id = 52 to return eveything

pi_region_id = 1 for example, to return rows on INICATORS where HRCC_ID = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:  Not sure why you need PL/SQL, this seems like something you should be able to do in standard SQL.  In the CASE statement you used := in one place, which is the PL/SQL assignment operator - where you probably wanted to test for equality. Finally, you shouldn't need the CASE construct - your WHERE clause can be stated like this:

```
...
where (pi_region_id = 52) or (pi_region_id = 51 and i.hrcc_id is null)
   or (pi_region_id != 51 and i.hrcc_id = pi_region_id)
```

Explanation: if pi_region_id = 52, the first condition is true, so all rows are returned. Otherwise, if pi_region_id = 51 or != 51, return rows according to your rule.  The parentheses are not necessary (precedence of AND over OR), but they help with readability.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for replying. It almost works. The only condition that doesn't works is the second one "(pi_region_id = 51 and i.hrcc_id is null)" when I put 51 for the pi_region_id input parameter, it should return 6 rows but doesn't return any.

Comment: Then there must be problems in other parts of the query. If you can show a representative sample of your tables, we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: For example: some hrcc_id may be rejected by your join condition, before you ever get to the where clause.

Comment: Riiiiiiiiight! I didn't think of that. So how do I join my 2 tables if I have a pi_region_id that is not 51 or 52?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing your tables!  :-) ... and without a statement of exactly what you are trying to achieve (the rules, in plain English rather than in SQL).   WITH THAT SAID:   It seems some hrcc_id may be null in one table or the other, so perhaps you need an outer join. On which side (or perhaps both?) depends on your tables, rules, and possible foreign key / primary key relationships between the hrcc_id's.

Comment: I've edited my initial post with more info... and then I saw the edits in your comments and it worked. I added a LEFT JOIN. Thank you!!!